# SQL Query: How to count occurrence of a specific value in a column without grouping on that column?

Tags: sqlite, group-by, count, conditional-statements, case

I have a table like this:

```
id | value
1  | a
1  | a
1  | b
1  | c
2  | a
2  | a
2  | a 
2  | c
```

And I want to `count(*) by id` and then `count(value==a) by id`, which means this is the desired results:

```
id | total_counts | a_counts
1  |      4       |   2 
2  |      4       |   3
```

I know how to do it by joining two subqueries, but is there an easier/faster way to do it? Like this pseudo-code:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS total_counts, COUNT(value==a) AS a_counts
FROM table
GROUP BY id
```

Not sure if there is a way to do the `COUNT(value==a)` part. Please kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `SUM`:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS total_counts, SUM(value='a') AS a_counts
FROM table
GROUP BY id;
```

Or if you have SQLite 3.25 you could use windowed version:

```
SELECT /*DISTINCT*/
     id,
     COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY id) AS total_counts,
     COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE value = 'a') OVER(PARTITION BY id) AS a_counts
FROM tab
```